# How to get battery level change in android (only when there is level/percent change)?

Tags: android, power-management

Is there a way to get battery level only when the level changes?

I know how to get the battery info using `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and then I compare the battery level of it with the last battery level (that I saved before) in case it equals I don't do anything else I do my stuff.

I also know that `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` happens when there is battery info change (not only the level) so cause of that I need to check the level. I don't know why but sometimes it doesn't work well.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it dosen't work well"? Do you miss broadcasts? Or did nothing change when you get one?

Comment: I don't know exactly cause it didn't happen in my phone and I could't recreate it. but I think that the check that I do didn't pass well so I wanted to know if there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no other (documented) way to get the battery level. Just ignore the broadcast when the level did not change. As you already do.

You can get the latest status immediately with the following:

```
IntentFilter batIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent battery = this.registerReceiver(null, batIntentFilter);
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
Log.d("TAG", "Current Level: " + level);
```

Comment: Do I need to unregister it? The receiver is null so I think I don't, is it correct?

Comment: I tried it and it dosen't work. I called this from another receiver of battery_changed and it gives me the same level...and not the last one.

Comment: Yes I know what you meant, it didn't work. I got the current level and not the last\latest. For example: after the battery level changed from 84 to 85, using you code I get 85 instead of 84.

Comment: How is that not the latest (aka newest) reported level? If you want to have access to the latest but one level (the level before the latest) just write the latest to the SharedPreferences and read it from there when you get it the next time.